# Java how to initialize constructor with abc parameter

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

```
/* Standalone java class file AbcDef.java */
    public class AbcDef {
        public void AbcDef(Abc[] abc) {
            something ???;
        }
    }
```

(**My Question 1**. I don't know how to handle above initialize)

```
/* Standalone java class file Abc.java */
    public class Abc {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        // Constructor...

        // Getters...

        public void setAbc(String nName, int nAge) {
            name = nName;
            age = nAge;
        }
    }

/* Another Test class file TestAbcDef.java */
    public class TestAbcDef {

        AbcDef[] tAbcDef = new AbcDef[];

/* e.g. i need to assign 10 records into tAbcDef[x] */
/* tAbcDef[0] = (name[1], age[1]),(name[2], age[2])....
```

(**My Question 2**. I don't understand how to initial and assign value to the array)
Any expertise can point me out to complete this. Thanks!!

Comment: Does your code even compile?

Comment: You made a method with the name of the class, instead of a constructor. Remove the `void`.

Comment: trying to define a constructor or a method..?

Comment: Q1 is want to define and initialize constructor. Thanks Abhishek.

Comment: Noted, i always mixup constructor and method. Thanks Martijn.

Comment: my code consist other method for reference, so absolutely compile with error. I need to step by step to clear my issue first. Thanks almas shaikh.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**
It depends on what you want to do in the constructor. With the constructor you will prepare the object before it can be used. Knowing that you can:

- Live it blank (Nothing is wrong with that, and it will work but I guess you want to do something with your abc parameter.
- Make something with your parameter. You can initialize one class variable, as an example:

  ```
   public class AbcDef {
      Abc[] arrayABC
      public void AbcDef(Abc[] abc){
          arrayABC=abc; // initialize class variable arrayABC with abc parameter.
   }
  ```

  }

You can read [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html) about constructors.

**Question 2**

When you declare an array, you have to consider that array length its fixed, so you should set it when you create it. This can be done this way:

```
 AbcDef[] tAbcDef = new AbcDef[9];
```

So you're saying  my declared tabcdef array is an AbcDef array with a length equals 9.

Once you got it created you can fill it by doing

```
tAbcDef[0]= whatever;
...
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class AbcDef {
    private Abc[] abc;
    public AbcDef(Abc... abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }  
}

public class Abc {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Abc(String nName, int nAge) {
        name = nName;
        age = nAge;
    }
}

AbcDef tAbcDef = new AbcDef( new Abc( "joe", 10 ), new Abc( "Bill", 20) );
```

Or, if you need an array of AbcDef:

```
AbcDef[] vAbcDef = new AbcDef[3];
vAbcDef[0] = tAbcDef;
vAbcDef[1] = new AbcDef( new Abc( "Sue", 30 ), new Abc( "Liz", 40) );
vAbcDef[2] = new Abc( "PEte", 50 ) );
```

An alternative way for defining an array length is by providing all the elements:

```
AbcDef[] vAbcDef = new AbcDef[]{ tAbcDef, 
                                 new AbcDef( new Abc( "Sue", 30 ), new Abc( "Liz", 40)),
                                 new AbcDef( new Abc( "PEte", 50 ) ) };
```